# How Can I hide/show menu item based on Logged users Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC 4 application. The _Layout master view contains a menu and I want to hide some of the items in the menu based on if you are logged in as a user and make show if you are logged in as an admin.

the approach that i have tried do hide the link tab within the menu for the client but however when i do login as an Admin it also hides the same link tab when i want it the admin to view it.

Just to mention i do not have any role or admin controller the login is based on the users

would appreciate some help thanks in advance.

```
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rep Home", "Index" , "Audit")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "Login" , "Home")</li>  
    @if (ViewContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <li><a href="http://example/reports/?report=auditDetails" target="_blank">View  your report</a></li>
    }        
</ul>
```

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }





<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Delete your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929331/struggling-to-hide-show-menu-item-based-on-logged-users-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i didnt get the answer that i wanted ereaon why i have posted a new question

Comment: Do not abuse this site - either edit the other question and delete this one, or delete the other.

Answer (score 9):

**Try this in your Layout page**

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  <li>Link to show only to logged users</li>
  if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
  {
    <li>Link show only to Admin </li>
  }
}
else
{
   links that will show to authenticated and unauthenticated users
}
```

**In your Controller add these lines**

```
Public ActionResult Login(UserModel model)
{
    // Check user provided credentials with database and if matches write this
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.id, false);
       return View();
}
```

And Finally in your Web.config add these lines inside System.Web

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Path of your Login view" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Remember you have 2 `Web.config` files and you have to add these files inside the lower `Web.config` file.

Comment: thanks for  you solution, i tried it but it still does the same, which i do not understand

Comment: Have you added  " FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(modal.id,false); " in your controller and  configured your web.config for Formatuthentication

Comment: No i do not know how to approach this process you mentioned do you have any example please?

Comment: In your Controller action add following code
***FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.id,false);***

Comment: And in Web.cofig file Inside <system.web> add following code

Comment: *** <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>***

Comment: I can send you the code if you provide you any mailing address

Comment: inside the index action?

Comment: can you copy my contoller post and update with the formauthentication so i can see where you would place it

Comment: No ,Inside the Action Where you are authenticating user like :-

Comment: ***controller action***

public ActionResult Login(UserModel model)
{
        // Match User Credentials With Database
         // if matches
         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);
}

Comment: i have done all the following changes you suggested but still the same

Comment: This code works fine , I think you have mistaken somewhere

Comment: Can you please share you Controller and Web.config Code

Comment: Your code is correct . Have you changed Layout View Code too?

Comment: yes i did too, here     @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))

  {


                    
                        <li><a href="http://example/Reports/?report=audetails" target="_blank">View your report</a></li>

                     }
                    
}

Comment: User.IsInRole("Admin") do not work right Now... User.IsAuthenticated will Work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129632/discussion-between-ghanshyam-singh-and-cazlouise).